# Copy/Paste Not Working in Modal Window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In my cocoa app I am displaying a NSPanel as a modal 'window' of another NSPanel using:

```
[modalPanel setWorksWhenModal:YES];
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] beginSheet:modalPanel modalForWindow:mainPanel modalDelegate:nil didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
```

This works, however the NSTextField's that show up in that modal 'window' are not allowing copy and paste.

From searching I found the following thread on Cocoabuilder which seems like pretty much the same problem, however there was no solution given in that thread either.

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/cocoa/2007/11/6/192462

That thread says to make sure you are not stopping copy/paste by using validation, but this is not the case for me as I currently do not have any validation on any of the fields.

Is there something special I have to do to get this to work, or does anyone have any ideas of what I could check/try?

Thanks!

Comment: Related question: [Cocoa Keyboard Shortcuts in Dialog Without an Edit Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970707/cocoa-keyboard-shortcuts-in-dialog-without-an-edit-menu)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is the "Edit" menu present in your application?

If you delete the edit menu, you lose the built in copy and paste functionality.

Comment: I dont have a edit menu as the program lives in the Status Bar and is displayed from the Status Bar menu or a global shortcut

Comment: That was it! I added a menu and hooked up the Edit items, and even though the menu doesn't show, it worked!

Comment: could you be more explicit about hooking up the edit items? I added the menu, and I still have right click paste but apple-v beeps at me.

Comment: if the edit menu items are not visible, in your menu, the shortcuts won't work but you will still be able to copy/paste/etc by right clicking

Comment: @KristopherJohnson archived version of that link: https://web.archive.org/web/20160414044036/http://www.shipsomecode.com/software/enabling-keyboard-shortcuts-with-nsstatusitems/