# Disable Cmd-Opt-Escape on fullscreen app

Tags: macos, cocoa, events, key, quit

I am using:

```
    if (CGCaptureAllDisplays() != kCGErrorSuccess) {
```

To capture the display and secure my app while the user is away, but users have reported, and I have confirmed that pressing  simply force quits my app.

How can I stop that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is a kiosk environment; see [Apple's Technical Note TN2062: Creating Kiosks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2062/_index.html).

Specifically, you'll want to use `-[NSApplication setPresentationOptions:]`; see `NSApplicationPresentationOptions` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for possible values.

Comment: Im using CGCaptureAllDisplays(); and Application is agent (UIElement): YES, which does not seem to support this, or creating an EventTap

Comment: I have been messing with this for hours, and can not get setPresentationOptions to stop Mission control working when run outside of XCode.  Anyone have working code that programatically creates a full-screen NSWindow "Lock Screen" that blocks the desktop, other apps etc, with simple button that then closes it if pressed.

Comment: I was about to point out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660996/lock-screen-on-mac-app but it looks like you've already found it. If this doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.