# How to make NSTextFieldCell Accept Keyboard copy/paste(cmd+c / cmd+v)

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste, nstextfieldcell

I am writing an editable NSTextFieldCell in a NSTableColumn, and everything goes well. 
But I found that my cell can accept the mouse right click copy/paste while does not respond to the keyboard copy/paste (cmd+c / cmd+v).
 Could someone please tell me how to make my cell support the keyboard copy/paste ? Should I customize my own cell and implement some method ?
Thanks!

Comment: i think it should "just work" did you remove the edit menu?

Comment: @GradyPlayer Yes. I do not have any menu item

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the edit menu items for copy / cut / paste etc, are what map the shortcuts to the actions.

see the similar question here: [Cocoa Keyboard Shortcuts in Dialog without an Edit Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970707/cocoa-keyboard-shortcuts-in-dialog-without-an-edit-menu)