# how can I handle the character palette hotkey in an LSUIElement application

Tags: cocoa, appkit, lsuielement

I've implemented something like [Cocoa Keyboard Shortcuts in Dialog without an Edit Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970707/cocoa-keyboard-shortcuts-in-dialog-without-an-edit-menu) for an LSUIElement application.  In fact, to try to make sure I was not missing some obscure standard keybinding that I might forget to include, I just grabbed a standard "edit" menu and loaded it out of a nib file and then used my `NSApplication` subclass's `sendEvent:` to invoke its `performKeyEquivalent:` .  This works as I expect.

However, the character palette (or "emoji picker", or "Emoji & Symbols") is not explicitly in this menu, so when I hit the hotkey (⌘⌃<kbd>Space</kbd>) nothing happens.  Examining the objects, this is what I expect. However, when I hit this hotkey in a *normal* application, I see the Edit menu flash as if that's where the key's defined, even if it isn't.  Stranger still,  still works even though the control-command-space one doesn't.

Where is this keyboard shortcut *supposed* to be handled? I don't want to do anything particularly custom here, I'd just like to correctly set up the default text-editing behavior that other apps get.

Comment: I *can* manually make this happen by wiring up a custom menu item in my hidden edit menu and setting its action to the Application nib object's `orderFrontCharacterPalette:` action, but this feels janky as heck. Is this how that's supposed to work?

Comment: Is the Emoji & Symbols item in the menu of the normal application at runtime?

Comment: I made a new app and *yes it is*! Wow that is weird. What is doing that?

Comment: `NSApplication` customizes the menus, have you tried "You just need to leave the original main menu in MainMenu.xib"?

Comment: @Willeke I haven't tried that but I guess I'll give it a shot at some point. I specifically *avoided* calling my bonus stock-menu UI `MainMenu.xib` so as not to conflict with any unwanted functionality. For the purposes of this question I will still give it a shot but I'm starting to wonder if I should just start up as a normal application so that these normal-looking windows have a normal-looking menu bar and `TransformProcessType` myself into the background when only the status item should be visible. Thanks for the suggestion!