macos background app SwiftUI TextField copy paste not working
I have this Form with two TextField's. When I attempt to use the copy paste shortcuts (CMD + C, CMD + V) within each TextField, I hear the typical macOS system interrupt sound, with no changes to the text or my clipboard. How can I make copy and paste work?
struct LicenseView: View {
    
    @State private var userLicenseKey: String = ""
    @State private var userEmail: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Email", text: $userEmail)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .frame(width: 340, height: 35)
                TextField("License Key", text: $userLicenseKey)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .frame(width: 380, height: 35)
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 500, minHeight: 500)
    }
}

Here is how I am displaying the LicenseView:
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    private var licenseWindow: NSWindow!
    
    private var statusItem: NSStatusItem!
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        if let button = statusItem.button {
            button.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "1.circle", accessibilityDescription: "1")
        }
        
        setupMenus()
    }
    
    func setupMenus() {
        let menu = NSMenu()
        
        let licenseItem = NSMenuItem(title: "License...", action: #selector(showLicenseWindow), keyEquivalent: "l")
        menu.addItem(licenseItem)
        
        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
        
        let quitItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q")
        menu.addItem(quitItem)
        
        statusItem.menu = menu
    }
    
    @objc func showLicenseWindow() {
        // Ensure the window exists; create if not
        if licenseWindow == nil {
            let hostingController = NSHostingController(rootView: LicenseView().frame(minWidth: 550, minHeight: 550))
            licenseWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: hostingController)
            licenseWindow?.level = .normal
            licenseWindow?.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
            licenseWindow?.title = "License"
        }
        
        licenseWindow!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true) // Focus the application
    }
}


Here is my app entry point main.swift file:
let app = NSApplication.shared
let delegate = AppDelegate()
app.delegate = delegate

_ = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)


Please show a [mcve].

Don't know what you are doing with the func showConfigurationWindow(),
but the Form{ TextField() ...} in a view works well for me,
ie copy and paste works.

@workingdogsupportUkraine even on a background macOS menu bar application, or just in a standard application?

@Sweeper I have edited the question so that it contains a minimum reproducible example.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/970707/77567

The post I linked explains the problem and provides AppKit solutions. I have voted to reopen this question because it deserves a SwiftUI solution.

@robmayoff Thanks for that link. I have tried the solutions in there just in case but it seems they are not applicable to SwiftUI. Do you think my best bet is to just rewrite this View in UIKit?

Actually I didn't notice earlier that you're creating your status item using AppKit, not as a SwiftUI MenuBarExtra. So you should just apapt one of the answers in the post I linked (specifically, one of the answers that subclasses NSApplication).

@robmayoff I have attempted to adapt those answers (specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29282997/13392841, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63552107/13392841) and it fixed my issue. Thank you.
